# Why are wrong bits extracted in python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, openpyxl

I need several k bits at position p extracted in order to convert to decimal value. I use a standard function but still when I test it for a 6/7/8 byte long binary code it is not correct. When I have a 1 byte code it is little-endian but once I use a 8 byte code it is shifted. For one signal (of a 7byte code) it was shifted +7bits but another signal (another ID, 8byte code) was shifted by -21bits. I cannot explain this to myself so I thought of playing around and manually add or subtract bits in order to use the correct bits for calculation. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

**Example 8bytes:**

```
extract_k_bits('100001111000000001110111011001000111011111111000001110100111101',16,0)
```

Output: `001110100111101` instead of `1000011110000000`

```
extract_k_bits('100001111000000001110111011001000111011111111000001110100111101',16,24)
```

Output: `0110010001110111` instead of `1011001000111011`

**This is the code I am working with:**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('Adapted_T013.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames 
print("All sheet names {} " .format(theFile.sheetnames)) 
sheet = theFile.active

def extract_k_bits(inputBIN,k,p):
        end = len(inputBIN) - p
        start = end - k + 1
        kBitSub = inputBIN[start : end+1]
        print(kBitSub)
        Dec_Values=int(kBitSub,2)
```

Comment: You are just slicing strings here, all the additional context about bits and bytes and signals is superfluous.  Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```py
def extract_k_bits(inputBIN,k): 
    # Since you always extract 16 bits
    # just use the point where you want to extract from
        kBitSub = inputBIN[k : k+16]
        print(kBitSub)

extract_k_bits('100001111000000001110111011001000111011111111000001110100111101',0)
extract_k_bits('100001111000000001110111011001000111011111111000001110100111101',23)
```

**Output**

[image: Output image]